# FileZilla FTP to public

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ftp

Today I was trying to set up an FTP server for my friend and myself. Server is in my home so I have no problem accessing it locally, but I am unable to open it to public. For my server configuration it is FileZilla server running on Windows 7 machine. I have disabled all firewalls so nothing is blocking it for now and I am able to connect to it in my local network.

What I have tried when it comes to opening it to local (on MikroTik router): 
I have created a firewall NAT rule to forward from my public IP address and port 776 to the server IP address on port 21 and what I get from FileZilla when trying to connect from external network:

```
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command: PWD
Response: 257 "/" is current directory.
Command: TYPE I
Response: 200 Type set to I
Command: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (31,134,50,169,198,229)
Command: MLSD
Error: The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
Response: 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

So as I see I am able to connect but can't actually read files. I know that there is this 'Passive Mode' problem, but from what I have read it is occurring when trying to connect, so it is not on me anymore? Correct me if I am wrong please.

I was also using this [site](https://ftptest.net/#result) to test for everything  but it showed errors. I am new to this kind of stuff and not very skilled when it comes to setting up connections.

This [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/647206/ftp-server-filezilla-windows-server) [from ServerFault] is talking about this stuff too, but I am unable to make it work. If anyone can explain to me step by step what do I do, please.

EDIT:

FileZilla output:

```
Command: MLSD
Error:    The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
Response: 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
Error:    Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

My NAT rule that forwards from my router IP and port 776 to server local port 21:

[image: NAT rule that forwards from my router IP and port 776 to server local port 21]

NAT rules that I have added to accept inbound and out traffic:

[image: NAT rules added to accept inbound and out traffic]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are only opening port 21, and you need to open a bunch of others:

- Outbound: TCP ports 1025 and above.
- Inbound: TCP port 21 and TCP ports 1025 and above.

Try this and should work ok.

However that's a HUGE range of ports. You can limit your exposure by configuring a lower range of ports in the filezilla server, let's say from (50,100 to 51,100):

- Open up the FileZilla GUI on your server.
- Click on the top menu Edit -> Settings.
- From the tree menu click on Passive mode settings.
- Now make sure the checkbox Use custom port range is checked and enter
  50100 in the first box a and 51100 in the second.

After that, make the same changes in your firewall, and you should be ok.

Comment: please see attached 3 pictures of what I have. I added that inbound and outbound accept but I guess it is not correct as it is still not working. I also addded my output from filezilla

Comment: I found this article that may compliment, and add a few other things to check for. Try the part where it says: This usually happens, when the server is not aware of its external IP address and reports its internal IP address.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758580/filezilla-the-data-connection-could-not-be-established-econnrefused-connec

Comment: https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FTPS_using_Explicit_TLS_howto_(Server)
https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration

I ahve tried the article but yeah, still got something wrong. I was hoping for it to be a quick and painless experience, but I will wrap my head around these two links, maybe they can provide some information I can understand. Thank you for your help, I will write if something changes

Comment: okay so after some configuration something hit my head. When doing all this stuff described in these links, do I need these ports on my NAT router to be opened? I mean my ISP have open ports in range of 770-790 in my router so I can use them for varius purposes. So assuming that these other ports are not 'open', will I not be able to forward packets through them??

Comment: Yes! When I said firewall I meant both in your router, your PC, and if you have anything in between. Did that fix it?